# How do I change a number in the array XAML in Window.Resources

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml, numbers

How do I change a number in the array. Please help.

I have a XAML array:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <x:Array x:Key="arrayOfInt32" x:Type="sys:Int32">
    <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
  </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
```

How do I change the number in the array using C# code from a button (Button_Click)?

And the code to update the progressbar value, from the array:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="listLights" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=StaticResource arrayOfInt32}}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" />
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="25" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar    
     Value="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" 
     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
     Name="pbLight"
     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
     VerticalAlignment="Center"
     Margin="4"
     Width="138"
     Height="17" />
   </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I'm sorry I did not show the code before. Corrected.

Comment: You certainly did not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface - it does not even make sense, since `StaticResource` is used for something static that does not change. You must bind to a property that has `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented.

Comment: You can't bind to array of ints because `System.Int32` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so your binding doesn't know when elements are changed. Create your own class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and bind it

Comment: Added a working solution for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
  int[] arrayOfInt32 = this.Resources["arrayOfInt32"] as int[];
```

or FindResource or TryFindResource methods.

There is a mistake in your XAML - it is not `x:Type` but just `Type="sys:Int32"`.

Though any updates you make to `arrayOfInt32` in your code will not show in `ProgressBar` because arrayOfInt32 does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so the `ProgressBar` control does not know that the change happened.

You can:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;    \
...

public partial class MyWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Observable collection 
    private ObservableCollection<int> _arrayOfInt32;
    public ObservableCollection<int> ArrayOfInt32
    {
        get { return _arrayOfInt32; }
        set
        {
            _arrayOfInt32 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    ....

    //Put this line in the constructor after InitializeComponent
    this.DataContext = this;
    ArrayOfInt32 = new ObservableCollection<int>(this.Resources["arrayOfInt32"] as int[]);
```

And modify XAML:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ArrayOfInt32}">
```

When you manipulte with values, do it with the ObservableCollection:

```
        ArrayOfInt32[0] = 50;
        ArrayOfInt32[1] = 80;
```

Comment: ProgressBar-s does not work on the form with the new numbers through the button (Button_Click). This is for only start form. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @VentDushan maybe post a bit more code, how do you update your `ProgressBar`

Comment: And `does not work` is not very comprehensible. It throws exception? It does not get updated as expected?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not show the code before. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var arr = Resources["arrayOfInt32"] as int[];
        arr[0] = 10;
    }
```

Comment: ProgressBar-s does not work on the form with the new numbers through the button (Button_Click). This is for only start form. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @VentDushan what do you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not show the code before. Corrected.